# Changing In App Billing v2 Subscription

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

Using IAB V2 it is possible to let users subscribe for your particular subscription id. 
But is it possible to  offer multiple subscription levels e.g basic ($1), silver ($2), Gold ($5), Platinum ($10 ) etc.. ?

User will get maximum functionality for say Platinum subscription (most costly) but only the bare minimum at Basic subscription (cheapest ).

I couldn't find any direct way of achieving this at present. What approach could be adopted using current IAB V2 to achieve this?  (Hope they will have something to offer in IAB V3 with subscriptions)